# Rails add file via controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, file

In the controller my Rails project, I would like to create a new file `/public/my_files/welcome.txt` with content

```
Welcome to my website!
```

(The folder `my_files` does not exist yet.)

How can I do that?

(Edit: I know that to make a static page, I don't need to do it via a controller. I'm actually making a dynamic page, but I'm just simplifying the example.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> File.open(Rails.root + '/public/my_files/welcome.txt', 'w') {|f|
>   f.write("your dynamic data") }

This is the simplest way you can create a file. Ruby will automatically create the file if not present. Let me know if this fits within your requirment.

Comment: Will it also create the `my_files` folder for me?

Answer (score 2):

I am not really sure what you asking about, but if you just want a static page you can do so without using the controllers

Just make a folder in the public dir (right click >> new >> folder) and make a html file in it.

Then start the rails server and point your browser to

localhost:3000/my_files/welcome.html

Comment: i think he wants to create a file in the public directory at runtime through a controller action. That's what im thinking right now.

Comment: I'm actually making a dynamic page, but I simplified the example. I've edited, and hopefully it's clearer now :)

Comment: I see. It does seem to go against the rails way. And that makes things harder than it needs to be. Why don't you just make a public_controller with corresponding views and routes? What do you mean when you say dynamic page? What kind of data are you displaying?

Comment: @AndreasLyngstad You're absolutely right.. Now that I think again, I should be able to do it the rails way like you said. It's good to know how to create a new file anyway!

Comment: @PaulS. Raghus answer your question well. When I stumble into a problem I can't get my head around. I always stop and rethink my design. There is usually an easier way. Glad that even tough I really didn't answer you question, I could be of some help.